# How to restore in fully connected layer using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series

train.py:

```
prediction = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1, :], 
                                output_dim, activation_fn=None, scope="prediction")
```

test.py:

```
prediction = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prediction:0")
```

After save the graph from train.py, I want restore for prediction variable in *test.py*, but not working.

'**tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected**' does not have a *name* parameter. There is only *scope* parameter. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the name that tensorflow defined  for you for the fully connected layer:

train.py

```
print(prediction.name)
```

it will be something like `prediction/BiasAdd:0`

use that name in test.py to correctly restore the variable